# how to use regular expression for this below stuff in php

Tags: php

I have a database of more than 70000 records and its primary key value started from 1 single digit.

So I want user have to type `nm0000001` instead of `1` in url.And in code part I have to discard the rest of the value except `1`.

But my problem is i want this type of things having 9 letters in the string and the pattern is like this

```
1    - nm0000001
9    - nm0000009
10   - nm0000010
2020 - nm0002020
```

And from the above pattern i want only the digits like `1,9,10,2020` in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the value is received in the URL as a querystring parameter, that is, passed via `$_GET['id']` or some other name than `id`:

```
// Trim the "nm" off the front
$pk = substr($_GET['id'],2);
// And parse out an integer value.
$id = intval($pk);
```

Comment: I think his problem is that he doesn't know where the 0's end and the actual ID starts. That's why he's trying to use a regex.

Comment: @Zach Doesn't matter.  If you trim off the nm from the front, `intval` will cast the rest of the number as the appropriate integer no matter how many zeros pad the front of it.  Ex: `echo intval("000023345");` prints `23345`.

Comment: Was originally my idea as well. Avoid the use of regex when possible!

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
$i = (int)substr($input, 2);
```

No reason to use regexes at all.

Anyway, if you're insisting on using regexp, then:

```
$input = 'nm0002020';
preg_match('~0*(\d+)$~', $input, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: i think you didn't get my question.Im not mentioning that the starting position from 2.

Comment: @pravat231 The "starting position from 2" trims off the "nm" from the beginning

Comment: @pravat231: well, I got it according how you have described it. And seems like 2 other guys got it in the same way. So you need to rephrase your question to get another answers.

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely no use for regular expressions in this -- use `sprintf("nm%07d", ...)` to format and just `substr` and a cast to int to parse.

Answer (score 0):

This function will do the trick:

```
function extractID($pInput)
{
    $Matches = array();    
    preg_match('/^nm0*(.*)$/', $pInput, $Matches);
    return intval($Matches[1]);
}
```

Here's why `/^nm0+(.*)$/` works:

1. The line must start (`^`) with exactly one `nm`
2. The pattern must continue with at least one `0`
3. At the first non-zero character after `nm0`..., capture the value (that's the job of the parentheses)
4. Continue until the end of the line (`$`)

Comment: When he will reach 7-digit identifier this regex will fail